# How to fetch record order by id?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table `users`

**users**

```
 id       | username       |is_active
----------|----------------|------------
 1        | chinu          | 1  
 2        | sradhanjali    | 1
 3        | User3          | 0
```

I have a list of user ids in an array that is `array(2,3,1)` I want to get records below order.

```
 id       | username       |is_active
----------|----------------|------------
 2        | sradhanjali    | 1  
 3        | User3          | 0
 1        | chinu          | 1
```

I have tried -

Query:

```
select * from users where id IN(2,3,1)
```

But this query does not return the correct result which I want.

If anybody knows how to write this query. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with your result? Maybe you need to add order by (2,3,1)?

Comment: Use `ORDER BY FIELD(id, 2, 3, 1)`

Comment: @Jens  I need order by id `2,3,1`

Answer (score 3):

you can use order by field

```
select * from users where id IN(2,3,1) order by FIELD(id,2, 3, 1) ;
```